# Combining types for a servant endpoint

Tags: haskell, types, dependent-type, servant

Using servant, I've got a type like the following, but more complex:

```
type MyAPI endpointTail result = "blah" :> Capture "a" A :> endpointTail :> Get '[JSON] result
```

Which means I can do things like this:

```
MyAPI "hello" HelloT
```

but when I do:

```
MyAPI "hello/world" HelloWorldT
```

Servant silently fails to produce my endpoint correctly, presumably because it doesn't expect a literal slash

When I try:

```
MyAPI ("hello" :> "world") HelloWorldT
```

I get a type error because `:>` is only defined when the right argument is of kind `*`, which `"world"` is not, it's of kind `Symbol`.

It seems for `servant` to work correctly, the `:>` has to be applied in a right associative fashion, one can't just add brackets willy nilly. So what I think I need is something like this:

```
type MyAPIF endpointTailF result = "blah" :> Capture "a" A :> endpointTail (Get '[JSON] result)
```

Note `endpointTail` is now a type function, `endpointTailF`.

Then I could do

```
type Blah t = "hello" :> "world" :> t

MyAPIF Blah HelloWorldT
```

But now I've got the issue of the compiler saying it doesn't like `Blah` being partially applied.

So in summary, I've got a nice reusable `type` which I'd like to keep using, I'd just like to be able to pass more parameters. If these were values I'd be able to do this easily, by passing a function "continuation" style, but I'm not sure of the solution in the type world. Any ideas?

Comment: In your penultimate code snippet, should `endpointTail` on the right-hand side be `endpointTailF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deductions are all correct. Unless you want to crawl down the rabbit hole that is [singleton defunctionalization](https://blog.jle.im/entry/introduction-to-singletons-4.html) (the usual method for working with partially applied type functions), you'll want to avoid treating type functions as arguments.  Use a plain data structure instead.

For example, if you write a type function that prefixes a type using a list of URL path segments:

```
type PrefixWith :: [Symbol] -> Type -> Type
type family PrefixWith segs t where
  PrefixWith (seg:segs) t = seg :> PrefixWith segs t
  PrefixWith '[] t = t
```

and then incorporate a call to this function within your API:

```
type MyAPI endpointTail result
  = "blah"
  :> Capture "a" A
  :> PrefixWith endpointTail (Get '[JSON] result)
```

then this lets you write:

```
MyAPI ["hello","world"] HelloWorldT
```

Full code example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Servant
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Kind
import GHC.Generics
import GHC.TypeLits
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp

type PrefixWith :: [Symbol] -> Type -> Type
type family PrefixWith segs t where
  PrefixWith (seg:segs) t = seg :> PrefixWith segs t
  PrefixWith '[] t = t

type MyAPI endpointTail result
  = "blah"
  :> Capture "a" A
  :> PrefixWith endpointTail (Get '[JSON] result)

data HelloWorldT = HelloWorld { success :: Int } deriving (Generic)
instance ToJSON HelloWorldT
type A = Int

main :: IO ()
main = run 8080 (serve (Proxy @(MyAPI ["hello", "world"] HelloWorldT))
                       (\n -> return (HelloWorld n)))
-- example URL, http://localhost:8080/blah/1/hello/world
```

Comment: I pretty much did exactly this, my bad for not updating the question with my own answer. Indeed the type family `Foldr` from the package `agda` does the trick: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Agda-2.6.3/docs/Agda-Utils-TypeLevel.html#t:Foldr